# Load the default values for the parentview controller in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, nsmutablearray

I have the current scenario as I am navigating between controllers with the `navigation controller` as well as `tab controller`. I want to keep track of all the variable and views within the controller which is pushed or tab changed. Is there any way to progress with that?
I have so far thought that I will take an `mutable Array` and push the object to that array and remove from them when the user loads the previous view controller again by pressing back. Am I in the right path? Please show me the right direction.

Comment: what is your requirement by doing this? Do you want to set some variable on currently displayed view controller?

Comment: No I want to load previous values of the viewcontroller which is pushed...

Comment: UINavigationController automatically keeps track of its view controllers within an NSArray. You can access them using the viewControllers property. `e.g. self.navigationController.viewControllers`. Same with UITabBarController.

Comment: Means you want to load some detail from previous one to current vc?

Comment: tabBarCtrl.selectedViewController will give you current viewcontroller/navigationcontroller as per your implementation and then self.navigationController.viewControllers can give you stack for view controllers

Comment: self.navigationController.visibleViewController will give you current viewcontroller loaded in navigationcontroller. From there you can store values in appdel variable or userdefault and use it any where.

Comment: Yes we can get the pushed view controller from the above code as you have mentioned, but how can we get the previous data which was then called from the webservice? There are thousands of data for the service including the images, will that be right if we store these data in the NSUserdefaults ar any variable?